# Should I learn more javascript to learn Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I've been programming on and off for about 2 years now  with python and C++, and a little bit of other languages like html, css, etc. I'm familiar with object oriented design and basic syntax of many languages. One that I've recently gotten into is javascript. About two months ago I heard about Angularjs and its capabilities. However, I've never done javascript at the time so I thought I'd give myself a few weeks to get familiar with javascript before I tackle Angularjs. A few weeks turned into 2 months and getting familiar is harder than I thought. However, I didn't want to stick to learning javascript forever, I wanted to move on the real goal and that is to learn Angularjs. So I started doing tutorials on Angularjs about a week ago. Now I'm stumped. It is very confusing to me. All the directives, MVC, controllers and such are so difficult for me to grasp. Experienced developers don't seem to have trouble picking up the framework, but I am so lost. I'm forcing myself to grind on it every single day until it makes sense but I'm rapidly loosing motivation because I don't understand most of it. Is this due to the fact that I still don't know enough javascript to grasp it? Will I have to learn more javascript to learn it? Frankly, I enjoyed javascript that's why I was able to keep doing it for 2 months. But my future for Angularjs is not looking very good and it has only been a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would definitely help to understand vanilla JavaScript more as well as having a better idea of what is going on "behind the scenes" in a web app. If your knowledge is fuzzy and you don't understand vocabulary / concepts being used, you cannot assimilate new information about those concepts. Take your time, no need to rush. Read a book or some articles about MVC - get a good idea of what is happening all the way around. And don't limit yourself to Angular (great as it may be). [Some light beginner reading](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/27/journey-through-the-javascript-mvc-jungle/)

Answer (score 0):

I would pick up some books on MVC.  The more "big picture" understanding you have the easier it will be to implement in AngularJS.  Check out Amazon for well reviewed books.